# Finding the list permutation with minimum score

Tags: r, performance, optimization, permutation, vectorization

I need to apply a function to all the permutations of a list and get the one which the result is the lowest.

Currently I have something like this (it uses `library(combinat)`):

```
scorePermutation <- function(permutation) {
  acc <- 0
  p <- 1
  for (x in permutation) {
    #very simplified version of the orginal for block
    acc <- acc + x/p
    p <- p*1.02^(x/p)
  }
  names(acc) <- paste(permutation, collapse=",")
  return (acc)
}

minScore <- function(items) {
  scores <- permn(items, scorePermutation)
  return (sort(unlist(scores))[1])
}
```

I changed the scorePermutation function logic in order to make it simpler for the question, I know the code doesn't make much sense.

I'm trying to improve the performance, particularly I'm trying to do `permn(items, scorePermutation)` in a vectorized way, but any tip will help.

UPDATE

Currently the usage is like this:

```
minScore(c(15,8,42,16,4,23))
#4,8,15,16,23,42 
#       62.42506
```

But I only need the minimum scoring permutation (in the example "4,8,15,16,23,42")

UPDATE 2

Here is the code with the original logic:

```
minScore <- function(items, p) {
  f = function(x) scorePermutation(x, p)
  scores <- permn(items, f)
  return (sort(unlist(scores))[1])
}

scorePermutation <- function(permutation, startp) {
  acc <- 0
  p <- startp
  for (x in permutation) {
    acc <- acc + x/p
    p <- updateP(x, p) 
  }
  names(acc) <- paste(permutation,collapse=",")
  return (acc)
}

updateP = function(value, p) {
  wh = ceiling(value/p)/ 60
  cd = wh %/% 24
  rh = wh %% 24
  ldsh = pmin(10, rh)
  lduh = pmax(0, rh-10)
  shf = 1.02^(cd*10+ldsh)
  uhf = 0.9 ^(cd*14+lduh)
  np = p*shf*uhf
  np = pmax(np, 0.25)
  np = pmin(np, 4)  
  return (np)    
}
```

Comment: I guess it would be easier with some example data and desired output

Comment: I think this may be unnecessary. It appears that the minimum score would just be `scorePermutation( sort( c(15,8,42,16,4,23)))`

Comment: I feel speed improvements will come by improving `scorePermutation` so having the exact code (not its simplified version) will be useful.

Comment: @BondedDust I know, but it is because I replaced the original logic with some (very) dummy code that iterates over the for

Comment: @flodel I am more interested in improving the way that scorePermutation is called, I think it will help me to understand better how R works

Comment: there is nothing to improve there...

Comment: I suspect one can replace the for loop with `cumsum( permutation in some-expression involving ^(0:length(permutation))` but it would be pointless to work on that effort if that's not the real recursion function.

Comment: Ok, I posted the code. I thought that maybe something like using a matrix or passing the permutations in a different way could help without involving the for